# Json dumps returns "\u0001" for "\1". I need to print the exact characters "\1" after passing to json dumps

Tags: json, python-2.7, python-unicode

Here is my code:

```
import json    
a = "\1"
print json.dumps(a)
```

It returns "\u0001", instead of desired "\1".
Is there any way to get the exact character after passing with json dumps.

Comment: "\1" is not a valid json string. What you are trying to achieve?

Answer (score 0):

In Python, the string literal "\1" represents just one character of which the character code is 1. The backslash functions here as an [escape to provide the character code as an octal value](https://docs.python.org/2.0/ref/strings.html).

So either escape the backslash like this:

```
a = "\\1"
```

Or use the raw string literal notation with the `r` prefix:

```
a = r"\1"
```

Both will assign exactly the same string: `print a` produces:

```
\1
```

The output of `json.dumps(a)` will be:

```
"\\1"
```

... as also in JSON format, a [literal backslash (*reverse solidus*) needs to be escaped by another backslash](http://rfc7159.net/rfc7159#rfc.section.7). But it truly represents `\1`.

The following prints `True`:

```
print a == json.loads(json.dumps(a))
```